# Random nulls after json_encode

Tags: php, json

When I use json_encode on an array in PHP it has random nulls after it.

```
function GiveUserServer($DBConnect, $Headers) {
  $OpenSessions = FindOpenSessions($UserID, $DBConnect, $Headers);
  if (JoinSession($OpenSessions, $DBConnect)) {
    print_r($OpenSessions);
    echo json_encode($OpenSessions);
  } else {
    echo "error";
  }}

function FindOpenSessions($UserID, $DBConnect, $Headers) {
  $OpenServers = QueryAllOpenServers($DBConnect);
  if (is_array($OpenServers)) {
    $ChosenServer = $OpenServers[rand(0, count($OpenServers))];
    if ($ChosenServer[0] == "" OR is_null($ChosenServer) OR $ChosenServer == "null") {
        SetupForServer($Headers, $DBConnect);
      }
    return $ChosenServer;
  } else {
    return "No Servers Found";
  }}
```

QueryAllOpenServers($DBConnect); returns an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 0 [2] => 1 [3] => sadsa ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 0 [2] => 65 [3] => sdasdfasf ) )
```

I've print_r()'ed what FindOpenSessions returns

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 0 [2] => 1 [3] => sadsa )
```

and yet when I use json encode it returns

```
["2","0","1","sadsa"]nullnullnullnullnullnullnull
```

The amount of nulls also varies.

Comment: Show your `json_encode()` and the code around it.

Comment: Alright, updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding array_map(utf8_encode, $ChosenServer);